# only returning one value when web scraping

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

*Ultra Beginner here:

So I am trying to scrape a site and pull the blog titles off that site.  So far I have managed to pull the the list but when Ive set up a dict_list my code only pulls the last title instead of all 10. So how do I print all 10 titles and not just the final one?

```
import requests
import bs4
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.stuffyoushouldknow.com/blog/"

r = requests.get(url)

content = r.content 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'content'})


blog = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'content'})

blog_dict_list = []

for bloginfo in blog:
    text = bloginfo.getText()
    if len(text) > 0:
        blog_title = text.split (".") [0]
        read_more = text.split (".") [1]
        d = {'blog_title' : blog_title, 'read_more' : read_more}
        blog_dict_list.append (d)
```

Comment: What's the problem? Tested and it grabs all ten titles and the `read_more` just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could print just the titles by using a list comprehension to extract the titles from your dictionary list and printing them:

```
titles = [blog_dict['blog_title'] for blog_dict in  blog_dict_list]
for title in titles:
    print(title)
```

You can use trim to "clean" the titles by removing boundary **whitespace** with the **strip()** function:

```
print(title.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

If you just want to print the title use : `print(blog_title)` within the for loop.

Option 2(*As per answer by @craigsparks*):

If you want to store all the titles & print them later, parse the list & print only the titles.

```
titles = [blog_dict['blog_title'] for blog_dict in  blog_dict_list]
for title in titles:
    print(title.strip())
```